# Varnish as a cache in front of apache virtual hosts

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I would like to configure varnish as a cache for one of my websites for a temporary heavy load.

I set up several virtual machines with varnish that should cache my main website.
As my main server hosts several websites the apache server is configured to be a virtual host server.

So I defined the main website domainname in the default.vcl instead of an IP address, hoping varnish would propagate the requests properly to the right apache virtualhost.
But it seems it just uses the IP address, and is caching the apache default page that appears when sending a http request to my main website ip address.

Is there a way to configure varnish so it calls my backend using the right url, and not an IP:port ?

my varnish config looks like :

```
backend default{
  .host = "www.myvhost.com";   
  .port = "80"; 
}
```

instead of :

```
backend default{
  .host = "my.ip";   
  .port = "80"; 
}
```

because I need  the varnish instances : http://www1.myvhost.com, http://www2.myvhost.com ... to cache the main server http://www.myvhost.com
but not http://myip:80/

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You probably ean the varnish is the reverse proxy not the apache

> As my main server hosts several websites the apache server is
>   configured to be a reverse proxy.

You can configure your hostname in the backend definition of your default.vcl
https://github.com/mattiasgeniar/varnish-4.0-configuration-templates/blob/master/default.vcl

All your traffic is going to point on the varnish for all your vhosts, excepts if you have several IP on your server.

I think what you are looking for is flitering queries for a single domain. You can achieve this by filtering on the host.

```
sub vcl_recv {
   if (req.http.host ~ "(www\.)?yourdomain\.com") {
     return(pass);
   }
}
```

All traffic not on your domain will be directly pass to the backend without lookup

Comment: No, the main server is apache based, and it has a virtual proxy configuration for serving several websites.

I would like to place several varnish as simple caches on different computers to be able to cope with a temporary (one weekend) overload.
But I need the varnish to cache the right website, ie, one of the apache virtual hosts.

Varnish shouldn't cache <my ip:my port> but <my vhost url>

Comment: Your apache is delivering several websites by vhost not reverse proxy. The RP is in front of your apache. Maybe if you post your config files it would be clearer

Comment: Yes, you're right, I meant vhost for that one, it also does reverse proxying but I don't need those to be cached. I added my config to the main post... Thanks

Comment: I think you misunderstood how varnish works. You won't have  http://www1.myvhost.com on varnish. your actual server IP will be point to the varnish server. ALL your traffic is going to pass across the varnish. Your apache won't be accessible directly. Your apache can be into a private network without any public IP if you want.
So you have to check in the sub vcl_rcv routine if you want to lookup for a cache version or if you want to directly pass to the apache server (what you want for all others domains but your).

Comment: Yes I understood that the configuration you are describing is the standard way of using varnish. However i would like to put several front end caches (at least 4) with the main one still accessible and acting as a load balancer for the public parts. My site is not a standard cms but already optimized with memcache etc. And i formerly already used "custom managed" replicas to manage overloads. But syncs are quite complex as the site is highly dynamic. So i was hoping to find a more out of the box solution with varnish.

Comment: Anyway i have a quick and dirty solution which is serving my vhost also on a specific port and send all the varnishes there. But i expected a cleaner solution :-)